# Merge duplicate longs in an array

Tags: arrays, recursion, merge

I'm trying to merge/multiply duplicate longs in an array recursively.
So if I have something like that:
long[] arr = {3, 5, 6, 6, 7} => long[] arr = {3, 5, 36, 7}

That's what I've got:

```
    public static long[] merge(long[] ns, int i, Merger m) {
    m.merge();
    if(i > ns.length) return new long[0];
    if(i < 0) return merge(ns, 0, m);
    else {
        if(ns[i] != ns[i+1]) {
            return append(merge(ns, i-1, m), ns[i+1]);
        }
        else {
            return append(merge(ns, i-1, m), ns[i] * ns[i+1]);
        }
    }

    public long[] append(long[] old, long newLast) {
        long[] result = Arrays.copyOf(old, old.length + 1);
        result[old.length] = newLast;
        return result;
    }
}
```

But it stucks in its recursion.

Comment: Why you're calling m.merge();?
It looks like an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple cases that are not clear from the approach that you've taken.

What happens when there are multiple instances of the same value? Do they simply get multiplied? In your current logic, you check whether `ns[i] != ns[i+1]`, which assumes that a. the list if sorted, .b. that occurrences come up only in pairs.

To see why (a) holds, your current approach would not multiply the two `6`s if your input list were [3,6,5,6,7]. Is this a valid assumption to make?

To see why (b) holds, assume you had for input `[1,3,5,6,6,6,7]`. In this case, on multiplying the first two occurrences of `6`, your resultant list would be `[1,3,5,36,6,7]`, and your current logic would not end up multiplying 36 and 6.

Is this intended?

Before implementing a recursive solution, it would be instructional to write out the iterative implementation first. That way, the problem specification will become clearer to you.

Assuming these two assumptions hold for the specific problem you're trying to solve, the implementation below works. 
(Note - this is implemented in Python. if you're looking for a Java specific solution, you should modify your question specifying it + add a `Java` tag to your post. Someone fluent in Java can then help you out. This solution tries to resemble your approach as closely as possible.)

```
def merge(ns, i, resultant_list = None):
    if resultant_list is None:
        resultant_list = []

    if i > len(ns)-1:
        return resultant_list

    else:
        if i == len(ns)-1:
            append(resultant_list, ns[i])
            return resultant_list

        elif(ns[i] != ns[i+1]):
            append(resultant_list, ns[i])
            return merge(ns, i+1, resultant_list)

        else:
            append(resultant_list, ns[i] * ns[i+1])
            return merge(ns, i+2, resultant_list)        

def append(old, newLast):
    old.append(newLast)
    return old
```